# Google Play, screenshots for tablets and image order

Tags: android, screenshot, google-play

In Google Play it's now possible to have screenshots for phones, 7- and 10-inch tablets. I was trying to upload screenshots from an tablet on one of my applications. All my current screenshots where listed for phones.

After I uploaded one screenshots for both 7- and 10-inch tablets I get the following the result:

On my phone first the phone-images are listed first, and then the tablets images.
On my 7-inch tablet I first see the tablet images and then the phone images.

The documentation doesn't say anything about which images that will be visible for each screen size, or which order, so maybe this is the expected result :-).

Does anyone knows the logic behind this? I would like to have better control of the order.

Comment: when accessed from my phone and laptop my two tablet 10" and two 7" tablet, then first two shots show first, in that order, so there is a lot of duplication since i'm using the same two screenshots for all devices. very irritating.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will see first the screenshots that will best suit on the user's device. The idea is to show to the end user how it will actually look like on his/her device.

So if you are on a phone, you will see phone screenshots first. If you are on a 10-inch tablet you will see those screenshots first, and so on...

Comment: Thanks for answering. I was hoping that I could have better control, but it doesn't looks so.

If I publish screenshot of a game for instance I may want the first screen be the intro screen, the second the actual game and the third an highscore list. If I make screenshots for just one screen size the order will be correct, but resolution will be wrong. If I make screenshots for different resolutions the order will be incorrect.

I hope we get some improvements for this someday :-).

Comment: Why don't you create 8 screenshots for each resolution? Then you wouldn't have this problem!

Comment: Wouldn't the end users then see 24 images?

Comment: I don't think so, but I didn't test it! I think the max number of screenshots a user will see is 8!

Comment: I have tried it and it doesn't work like that. On my phone I was able to get 8 phone images, and 2 tablet images.

Comment: I have just posted eight images for 7-inch tablets and eight for 10 inch for one of my apps.  On my Nexus One phone, I see phone images first, then 10 inch images, then 7 inch images.  All 24 images are displayed.  On my Nexus 10 tablet, I see 10 inch images first, then 7 inch images, then phone images; all 24 again.  On my Nexus 7 tablet, though, the results are unexpected; phone images appear first, followed by 10 inch images, followed by 7 inch images.  I cannot explain this anomaly; I would have expected 7 inch images first on a 7-inch tablet.  On the Web, it is 10 inch, 7 inch, phone.

Comment: In fact it is pretty annoying that the users sees each screenshot triple. The screenshots are often the same for phone, tablet7 and tablet10 except for the resolution.

Answer (score 1):

If you are browsing on desktop, you will see all screenshot sizes that matches your devices. If you have a tablet and a smarthphone, you'll se both.

On devices, you will see first the screens that match your device, then the other screenshots.