# Google play shows all my screenshots

Tags: android, google-play

I have 5 screenshots for each device size (phone, 7" and 10"). But the play store displays all my screenshots (15) on every device.

I only want to display 5 screenshots for each device size.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I've noticed this when viewing in a browser from a PC also

Comment: did you find any solution? Check f.e. the profile of Facebook on Google Play ! Its completely normal - shows just phone screenshots

Comment: this  one gives more insight to the issue  :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16678176/google-play-screenshots-for-tablets-and-image-order?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

Just don't upload same screenshots for every size.
Upload first 2 screenshots for phone, 3 and 4 for 7" and 5 and 6 for 10" and etc...
You can divide those screenshots and upload under various size category.

Answer (score 1):

This is normal, and also happens on my published games. I was not able to find a way to only show screenshots for each screen size, so I'm not sure that this can be done!
By the way you can always state on that screenshots the dimensions of the screen (ie. stating on 10'' that this screenshot is for HD tablets)

Comment: I wouldn't say that this is normal. In fact it is pretty annoying that the users sees each screenshot triple. The screenshots are often the same for phone, tablet7 and tablet10 except for the resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Same thing. But I've noticed that appropriate screenshots showed first. I mean on smartphone first will be displayed screenshots for smartphones and for tablets at the end, on 7'' tablets - for 7'' tablets and so on.