# Google Play - multiple app screenshots

Tags: android, google-play

I have published my application to Google Play and uploaded 2 screenshots for each of the devices: phones, 7" and 10". On my phone I can see all of the screenshots (6), while it should actually show only 2.

I have read below questions on why Google Play shows multiple screenshots and could not find a solution.

How to show only the relevant screenshots for device type?

I have checked some trending applications and they seem to have got this right without duplication, so there has to be a way to change this.

Links:

[Google play shows all my screenshots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19636136/google-play-shows-all-my-screenshots)

[Google Play, screenshots for tablets and image order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16678176/google-play-screenshots-for-tablets-and-image-order)

Comment: Very likely they are releasing multiple APKs. I think its pretty fine to show all screenshots if your app does support it.

Comment: But it looks bad. When I search for an app on my phone, I do not want to see identical screenshots for tablets.

Comment: Alright, then [this](http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html) might help.

Comment: Interesting, I will try to publish 3 separate identical APKs then and will see how that goes